# weird smallmoney in MS sql to decimal in .Net

Tags: asp.net

i have a smallmoney value in db as 25.00 when i read it to .net decmial it became 25.0000 on the asp.net gridview. where did it tack on the extra two digits?

Answer (score 1):

This is totally a consequence of formatting - 
The actual value in the database is simply 25 in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply a case of the default precision and display of the various formats.  If you want the data to display in a certain format, it's best to be explicit about that format.

Answer (score 0):

smallmoney and money in SQLServer both have 4 digits of precision after the decimal.

The formatting in SQL is probably irrelevant to your scenario, but if you format it in SQL you have several options.